# matplotlib: candlestick charts with eventflags

Tags: python, matplotlib, flags, candlestick-chart

I need to show flags (e.g. "long" and "short") on a candlestick chart. Is there a possibility to do this with `matplotlib`? Or would it be better to use `bokeh` or an other library for this? Unfortunately I couldn't find any example on the web.

Something like this:
[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also read the [annotations tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html) first. If you have a specific question, ask a specific question, using a [mcve] of the issue and a clear problem description (i.e. in how far did other resources not help?).